# Inserted items need to be clickable but they dont delete

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have a form with a session that once i insert a item it comes into a list.
But now i need to make sure the items are clickable and once you click on it the item disappears.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Opdracht 5</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="boodschap"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<ul>
    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

        $_SESSION['boodschappen'][] = $_POST['boodschap'];

        foreach ($_SESSION['boodschappen'] as $boodschap) {
            echo "<li>".$boodschap."</li>";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['boodschappen'] = [];
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Preview of how it needs to look]

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to ask a specific question here, describe what _problem_ you are facing - and not _just_ give us a specification / requirement.

Comment: do you refer to the `list` items - that they are to be clickable once only?

Comment: you mean some fade out effects? and the same time removing it inside session? you'll need some js for that mix it with xmlhttprequest. if you want it to keep it simple, you'll need to submit again the form for each list item click

Comment: or add a checkbox on the left in each item, then submit it and use the checkboxes to process the form and remove them from the session

Comment: It's doable, with Ajax

Comment: ive never used Ajax nor xmlhttprequest before, so i guess its not doable with php only?

Answer (score 0):

A little workaround would be:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="remove" value="0">
    <input type="text" name="boodschap"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>

<script>

function remove(item) {

    document.getElementsByName('remove')[0].value = 'true';

    document.getElementsByName('boodschap')[0].value = item;

    document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].click();

}

</script>
```

And the PHP part:

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {


        if($_POST['remove']) {

            // Search array
            $pos = array_search($_POST['boodschap'], $_SESSION['boodschappen']);

            // Remove from array
            unset($_SESSION['boodschappen'][$pos]);

        } else {

            // Else set as new item
            $_SESSION['boodschappen'][] = $_POST['boodschap'];

        }

        foreach ($_SESSION['boodschappen'] as $boodschap) {
            echo "<li onclick=\"remove('".$boodschap."');\" >".$boodschap."</li>";
        }

    } else {
        $_SESSION['boodschappen'] = [];
    }

?>
```

Comment: this one works exactly how i need it, one little thing any way to make the items blue like in the picture

Comment: Add this after `head` tag `<style>
li{color: #3af;text-decoration:underline;}
</style>`

Comment: i need to make it a link not just the color

Answer (score 0):

To do this without constantly reloading the page every time a link is clicked you need to use either `XMLHttpRequest` or `Fetch` ~ ie: Ajax. Perhaps the following will prove useful.

```
<?php
    /* 
        start the session - do NOT call this within the 
        body of the HTML unless you are using output 
        buffering 
    */
    session_start();

    $svar='boodschappen';
    $field='boodschap';


    /* initialise the empty session variable */
    if( !isset( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){
        $_SESSION[ $svar ]=array();
    }


    /* Process form submissions, add new items to array */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ){

        /* allow a single item or a space separated series of items */
        $items=array_unique( explode( ' ', $_POST[ $field ] ) );

        /* add new item to session if it does not already exist in the array */
        foreach( $items as $item ){
            if( !in_array( $item, $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ) $_SESSION[ $svar ][]=$item;
        }
    }


    /* process ajax POST requests to remove item from session */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['item'] ) ){
        ob_clean();

        /* if the item exists in the array, find it's position and remove it */
        if( $_POST['action']=='delete' && in_array( trim( $_POST['item'] ), $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){

            $pos=array_search( trim( $_POST['item'] ), $_SESSION[ $svar ] );
            array_splice( $_SESSION[ $svar ], $pos );
        }

        /* send item name back to javascript callback which will remove it from the list */
        exit( trim( $_POST['item'] ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Opdracht 5</title>
        <style>
            body *{display:block}
            li,a{color:blue}
            input{padding:0.5rem;}
            [type='text']{clear:both;}
            [type='submit']{margin:1rem 0 0 0;}
        </style>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                const ingredients=document.getElementById('ingredients');

                const ajax=function( data, callback ){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback( this.response )
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', location.href, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send( data );
                };

                const callback=function(r){
                    ingredients.removeChild( ingredients.querySelector('li[ title="'+r+'" ]') );
                    if( ingredients.childElementCount==0 )console.info('List cleared');
                };

                ingredients.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    /* use `event delegation` to register clicks to child elements */
                    if( e.target != e.currentTarget && e.target.tagName=='A' ){
                        ajax( 'action=delete&item='+e.target.innerText, callback );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='boodschap' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <ul id='ingredients'>
            <?php
                if( !empty( $_SESSION[ $svar ] ) ){
                    foreach( $_SESSION[ $svar ] as $boodschap ) {
                        printf('
                        <li title="%1$s"><a href="#">%1$s</a></li>', $boodschap );
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```